# Using 'insertbefore' with Bootstrap Popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

Hi hopefully this is easy for some of the experts.

I am currently working on a calendar application, using Bootstrap and have caused a popover to appear on a dynamically added element in the DOM.

```
$('.calendar-close-popover').on('click',function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
    $('#'+events[0]._id).popover('destroy');
});
```

I use the above to target a button within the popover which will cause it to close.

When I use this code below to reposition my popover I have no problem, the popover will close:

```
$('.popover').css('left',posDef.leftOffset.left - posDef.leftCenterNudge); // position centerally on the day
```

but if I use 'insertbefore' it stops:

```
$('.popover').insertBefore('.fc-event-container').css('left',posDef.leftOffset.left - posDef.leftCenterNudge); // position centerally on the day
```

I am assuimg that Bootstrap does not like me moving things around the DOM using 'insertbefore' after they have been created, because why? and how can I target this now please?

Hi yes I've added an example to my site here:

http://liebecampbellroberts.com/calendar/pages/new-event-test.html

Comment: what does the html look like?

Comment: We need the relation between $('#'+events[0]._id) and $('.popover').
Is there a reason to destroy popover instead of closing it ?
Maybe you should try to use console.log() in your event callback to know if the event is called...

Comment: Can ou provide a demo of the issue on jsfiddle?

Comment: Hi guys, yes I have added  a demo here:http://liebecampbellroberts.com/calendar/pages/new-event-test.html

Comment: If you click on an event on the 21 May 2014 it will render my popup, the problem is that I used 'insertafter' in JQuery to relocate my popover due to a z-index clash.  Then I reposition the calander over the event clicked.  I have got it to work, but it seems that once shown, Bootstrap can not then find the same popover to then remove it, try clicking on the trash can, I have got this to work by using $(.popover).remove(), but know i should be using $(element).popover('destroy') as it will update the event, not just remove it from the DOM.Getting rid of the 'insertbefore()' it works, but why?